# Android Studio - OS X : 'Dvorak - Qwerty ⌘' layout shortcuts switching doesn't work in Android Studio

Tags: macos, layout, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, dvorak

'Dvorak - Qwerty ⌘' layout, which map my key back to qwerty if i press ⌘ simply works well in most app but not Android Studio with Keymap Mac OS X 10.5+. Anyone have a workaround? Or I should just change my layout on my Mac back to just 'Dvorak' ?.

Comment: did you fix the problem? I am stuck in the same problem right now

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is looking for this - in my current version of Android Studio (v2.3.3), you can go into `Android Studio > Preferences` and select the `Keymap` option in the Preferences Pane.

From there, you can re-assign your shortcuts. I did the big ones: Find, Copy, Paste... When you reassign them, it will show Dvorak keys for the shortcuts - my shortcut for Find (Cmd + F) shows up as CMD + U.

Also, be sure to choose the `Remove` option, to remove any previously existing actions that might be paired with your new key combos.

And don't forget to hit `Apply` and not just `OK` !

Comment: Being unable to use Dvorak+QWERTY cmd is sad :(

Comment: You can generally set these keyboard shortcuts within each app. @Hlung

Comment: But that would defeat the purpose of Dvorak+QWERTYcmd keyboard layout 